# how to make submenu not affect layout?

Tags: html, css

The page I am working on is here:

www.dqhendricks.com

As you can see, currently the submenu is pushing the next menu item to the right. I am trying to get the submenu to not affect the layout (without needing to put a set width on the containing `<li>` tag). Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see it. What browser + version are you using? P.S.  Your graphics look well done and all, but the site needs more color contrast with some darker colors.  Right now it's really washed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use position:absolute on submenu;

```
#nav .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}
```